# I get this error in vscode with flutter MainActivity.java is no on the classpath of project app,only syntax errors are reported

Tags: java, flutter, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use `methodchannels` to write native Java code for my Flutter project but I get this error:

`MainActivity.java is no on the classpath of project app,only syntax errors are reported`

I have tried to restart VC code, to create a new project with Java as primary language ,
to right click in the folder and press "**add folder to java source path**" but I get `unsupported operation. pls use build.gradle file to manage the source directories of gradle project` ,

I also tried Press "Ctrl + Shift + P", choose "java : Clean java Language Server workspace,
I also tried all of the above combined but it didn't work

When I create the project with Kotlin language it works fine but I don't want to use Kotlin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem . java extension for vscode dont work for android/flutter dev , i just uninstalled it and it worked fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).